# Is there a way to replace values avoiding nan where the condition is not met?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, str-replace

I'm trying to replace noisy values (',') to transform a dataframe column into a numeric column. The problem occurs when str.replace override with nan all values that doesn't contain any comma.

to illustrate the problem:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'transaction_number': [1344, '1,345', 1346, '1,347'],
    'date': ['2018-12-01 14:03:38',    '2018-12-01 12:38:12',
'2018-12-04 13:19:46',   ' 2018-12-04 12:23:09']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```py
    transaction_number  date
0   1344    2018-12-01 14:03:38
1   1,345   2018-12-01 12:38:12
2   1346    2018-12-04 13:19:46
3   1,347   2018-12-04 12:23:09
```

First thing i tried:

```py
df.transaction_number = df.transaction_number.replace(',', '')

#i tried this equivalet too:
df.transaction_number.replace(',', '', inplace = True)
```

neither of them made any transformation to the data (that is, they did nothing). If someone could tell me why i'll be so grateful.

Finally i tried (str method):

```py
df.transaction_number = df.transaction_number.str.replace(',','')
```

and returns:

```py
    transaction_number  date
0   NaN    2018-12-01 14:03:38
1   1345   2018-12-01 12:38:12
2   NaN    2018-12-04 13:19:46
3   1347   2018-12-04 12:23:09
```

I don't know what and why is happening this, my desired outcome is:

```py
    transaction_number  date
0   1344    2018-12-01 14:03:38
1   1345    2018-12-01 12:38:12
2   1346    2018-12-04 13:19:46
3   1347    2018-12-04 12:23:09
```

Please help and thank your for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need option `regex=True` on `replace`

```
df['transaction_number'] = df.transaction_number.replace(',', '', regex=True)

Out[12]:
                   date transaction_number
0   2018-12-01 14:03:38               1344
1   2018-12-01 12:38:12               1345
2   2018-12-04 13:19:46               1346
3   2018-12-04 12:23:09               1347
```

Comment: Thank you! Just for curiosity why regex=True is needed. I'm new with pandas and i'm curious about detais :).

Comment: @Jose_Chavez: without `regex=True`, `replace` checks on the whole string. So, it failed to find `','`. I.e, default  `regex=False` will check on the whole string. `regex=True` will check on regex pattern and found `','` and properly replace it. Note: `replace` is different from `str.replace`

Answer (score 2):

That is happening because your column has mixed data types. We can convert it all to string(using `.astype(str)`) and then apply the replacement.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'transaction_number': [1344, '1,345', 1346, '1,347'],
    'date': ['2018-12-01 14:03:38',    '2018-12-01 12:38:12',
'2018-12-04 13:19:46',   ' 2018-12-04 12:23:09']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.transaction_number = df.transaction_number.astype(str).str.replace(",","")
print(df)
```

Output

```
  transaction_number                  date
0               1344   2018-12-01 14:03:38
1               1345   2018-12-01 12:38:12
2               1346   2018-12-04 13:19:46
3               1347   2018-12-04 12:23:09
```